# Probability of getting at most 4 and at least one 4 in 5 consecutive die rolls

Tags: probability

Let's suppose we have one die. We roll it 5 consecutive times. How can we calculate the probability of getting at least one 4 and at most 4 in all the 5 rolls of the die. Let me explain the case with some example successful and failed cases

1 3 4 4 4 -> success

4 1 1 2 1 -> success

4 4 4 4 4 -> success

1 2 3 4 1 -> success

1 2 3 4 5 -> fail

5 6 5 6 4 -> fail

1 2 3 2 3 -> fail

I am not sure if I have been able to ask and explain the question properly. If further clarification is needed please do not hesitate to ask.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand. Why are the $4^{th }$ and $5^{th}$ sequences failures? They each contain precisely one $4$. Also, in the title of your question you specify $10$ consecutive rolls, but in the question itself you specify $5$. Which is it? Finally, why don't you show what you've tried already - I doubt anyone will want to help otherwise.

Comment: Yes you need to clarify - it doesn't make sense as is.

Comment: Possibly because they have a $5$ or $6$, which are more than $4$: the question says "at most $4$"

Comment: Thinking about these questions might be useful: a) What is the probability of getting no 5s or 6s in $n$ consecutive rolls of a fair die? b)  What is the (smaller) probability of getting no 4s, 5s, or 6s in $n$ consecutive rolls of a fair die?

Comment: Rookatu: I am sorry that I have messed up with the title. I meant 5 rolls for a single die. I forgot to change it in the title.

4th and 5th sequences are failures because of the reason Henry stated. The acceptable case must contain at least one 4 and at most 4s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional probability:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \land B)} {P(B)}$$

- A is probability of rolling at least one 4
- B is probability of not rolling a 5 or 6

P(B) is simple, $(4/6)^{10}$

P(A|B) means "the probability of A, assuming B is true".  The probability of rolling at least one four, given that you are only rolling values one through four, is the same as if you were rolling a four sided dice:  $1 - (1 - 1/4)^{10}$

$$\begin{align}P(A \land B)  &= P(A|B)P(B)\\
&= (1 - (1 - 1/4)^{10})(4/6)^{10}\\
&= \frac{989527}{60466176}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Your answer seems logical and correct to me. If anybody has any other observation please share

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- How many equally probably ways are there of rolling five (or ten) dice?
- How many equally probably ways are there of rolling five (or ten) dice so that each is no more than $4$?
- How many equally probably ways are there of rolling five (or ten) dice so that each is no more than $3$?
- How many equally probably ways are there of rolling five (or ten) dice so that largest value shown is exactly $4$?

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing, you want to roll $10$ six-sided dice, and get at least one die showing $4$, and no die show either $5$ or $6$

There are $6^{10}$ distinct sequences of roll without restriction.

How many sequences are there that don't contain $5$ and $6$?

How many sequences are there that don't contain $4$, $5$ and $6$

Subtract, divide...